# How to convert any image to JPG or JPEG using PHP

Tags: php, gdlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save image from one format to another with php gd2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929587/save-image-from-one-format-to-another-with-php-gd2)

I am converting any image format to JPEG or JPG. Code for converting image to jpg is

```
function converttojpg($originalimg)
{
$filetype = @end(explode(".", $originalimg));
echo $originalimg . " asdasdfs";
if (strtolower($filetype) == 'jpg' or strtolower($filetype) == 'jpeg') 
    {
    $srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalimg);
    imagejpeg($srcImg,$originalimg,100);
    imagedestroy($srcImg);
    } 
if (strtolower($filetype) == 'png') 
    {
    $srcImg = imagecreatefrompng($originalimg);
    imagejpeg($srcImg,$originalimg,100);
    imagedestroy($srcImg);
    } 
if (strtolower($filetype) == 'gif') 
    {
    echo "executed";
    $srcImg = imagecreatefromgif($originalimg);
    imagejpeg($srcImg,$originalimg,100);
    imagedestroy($srcImg);
    }
}
```

After that i resize that converted image, whose code is

```
function resizeImage($originalImage,$toWidth,$toHeight)
{
// Get the original geometry and calculate scales
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalImage);
$xscale=$width/$toWidth;
$yscale=$height/$toHeight;

// Recalculate new size with default ratio
if ($yscale>$xscale)
    {
    $new_width = round($width * (1/$yscale));
    $new_height = round($height * (1/$yscale));
    }
else 
    {
    $new_width = round($width * (1/$xscale));
    $new_height = round($height * (1/$xscale));
    }
// Resize the original image
$imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$imageTmp     = imagecreatefromjpeg ($originalImage);
imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $imageTmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height           );
return $imageResized;
}
```

and on Every image it reports errors and warning which are

```
    Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 9 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9 in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 33

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'userphotos/corrupted_image_1.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 33

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 34

Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 35

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 9 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9 in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 22

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'userphotos/53.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 22

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\functions.php on line 23
userphotos/MG_diesel-04.gif_thumb.png asdasdfsuserphotos/Porsche_911_996_Carrera_4S.jpg asdasdfs
```

Please help me in solving that problem. I have to complete it.

Comment: Not sure about gd extension. Try Imagick. http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Using @ to suppress errors is never a good idea, especially if you are trying t work out why a script is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use extension to determine file type. To check if given file is an image and in format that allows GD to manipulate it, use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: Can't agree. See [`Caution`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) section.

Comment: Of course for non-image files or unrecognized image format it won't be much helpful, but more common cases are jpeg files saved with png extension.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $image = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_path));
        if ($image === false) {
            throw new Exception (sprintf('invalid image or file not found, file=%s', $file_path));
        }
?>
```

imagecreatefromstring detects image type and creates an image resource, otherwise exception is thrown.

Comment: Using @ to suppress errors is never a good idea, especially if you are trying t work out why a script is not working as expected.